# I'm installing a nest thermostat. The wires at the base are R G Y W

Tags: wiring, thermostat, nest

On my 24v transformer there is a C POST. I have wired the nest thermostat with the 4 wires R Y W G. Nest says the termostat needs a c wire,Can I just run a wire from the C post on the transformer to  the C hole on the thermostat?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram of your furnace please?

Comment: Is your thermostat cable 5 wires or only 4?  Often thermostat cables are installed with extra wires, they are wrapped around the cable sheath to keep them out of the way.  Pull the cable out of the wall a bit and see.

Comment: If you can run a wire from Transformer to the thermostat then do it. Are you sure it is not already there ?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other 192 questions in the [tag:nest] tag? There's probably already an answer to your question.